# rspec devise-confirmable render 'devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I have a devise confirmable on my user model, and I have tests on custom registrations_controller.

One of tests is like

```
      it 'renders :new template' do
        post :create, user: valid_params

        expect(response).to render_template(:new)
      end
```

But there is error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:new)
   expecting <"new"> but rendering with <["devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions"]>
```

How to get render of #new template?

Comment: What are the params you are sending to create? The test says `valid params`.. if the params is valid, then it won't `render_template(:new)`.. if one of the params is invalid, then it should `render_template(:new)`

Comment: Yes, it seems you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I got an error by myself. User just not created, so I got this error.

Comment: can you please explain me in details for your answer.